# How to add Variables in Drupal (and how to visualize them)?

Tags: configuration

I'm new to Drupal Answers, but I've been programming for a few years now.

I'm looking to create something simple (at least I think) within the Drupal CMS to use throughout the site. I want to create a variable, let's call it **$phonenumber** and store the value of this variable, like **(789) 456-7894** (not a real number). That way I may use the value of this variable on my site without hardcoding the number.

I have installed the [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module, which has little to no documentation, and poor usability all around.

I build in PHP, I know this is basic, Drupal is built on PHP. But for some reason I cannot get a **printr** or **echo** of the variable on any page to work.

Comment: This should set you on the right path: [Drupal 7 create custom form module with system variables](http://guillermocerezo.com/en/blog/codigo-php-cms-drupal/drupal-7-create-custom-form-module-system-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module? It is typically used in dev versions of a site only, and is not recommended for production status sites.

After you enable that module, you'll get many features, such as **dprint_r()**, **dpm()** (I like the last one for debugging). For more details, refer to https://www.drupal.org/node/174575 ...